# How to add the number in one column based on the numbers in other columns

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have a tab-delimited dataset like:

```
#1 2      3   4  5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19
1 10024 10395 41 K + 2 1 1 12 14  5  0  0  3  1  3  6 2 
1 10679 10795 51 P + 2 1 1 15 14  3  0  0  2  1  2  3 1
```

I want to add one more column ($20) to store the values based on column 7-19: if the number in a column is not equal to 0, then plus one.
Expected output:

```
#1 2      3   4  5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
1 10024 10395 41 K + 2 1 1 12 14  5  0  0  3  1  3  6 2  11
1 10679 10795 51 P + 2 1 1 15 14  3  0  0  2  1  2  3 1  11
```

How to write the command using awk?

Comment: how does `11` calculated in your logic?

Comment: Because in $7-19(total 13 columns) , $13 & &14 are 0, so 11=13-2; just to count the non-zero numbers in 7-19

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can iterate over the fields starting from 7-th, check if the value of the field is 0; if not, then keep incrementing 20-th field by 1:

```
awk -F '\t' 'NR==1 {$(NF+1)=NF+1; print; next}; \
            {for(i=7; i<NF; i++) if ($i != 0) $20++}; 1' OFS='\t' file.txt
```

For the first record (`NR==1`), added an extra field header as the last field with adding 1 to the current `NF`.

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -aF'\t' -lpe '$_ .= "\t" . ($. == 1 ? @F+1 : grep $_, @F[6..$#F])' data.set
```

Since we need to add another field at the end of line, we use the `.=` operator on the current record `$_`. For the special case of the 1st record, we simply append the the expression `@F+1`, which is interpreted in the scalar context to mean the current number of fields plus 1.

For the non-header records, the expression `grep $_, @F[6..$#F]` means iterate over the 7th element to the last of the `@F` array (which is carved out of the record using the tab field separator, specified via the `-F'\t'` option. In a scalar context, it returns the number of times the condition, in our case, a lone `$_`, to mean nonzero elements, in the slice 7th...upto last element.

---

## Result

```
#1 2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
1  10024 10395 41 K  +  2  1  1  12 14 5  0  0  3  1  3  6  2  11
1  10679 10795 51 P  +  2  1  1  15 14 3  0  0  2  1  2  3  1  11
```